# conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have problem with error from Title. The error ocures when I try to execute stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertTimeDate]
    @tableName as nvarchar(28),
    @timeStamp as datetime,
AS
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

BEGIN
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO [' +@tableName+'] (timeStamp) VALUES ('''+CONVERT(nvarchar, @timeStamp, 20)+''')'
EXEC (@query)
END
```

I execute it from c# code:

```
    dbCommand = new SqlCommand("insertTimeDate", dbConnection);
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "table_name");
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", DateTime.Now);
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with style 126 in your CONVERT - that's the ISO-8601 format which should work for any language/regional setting of SQL Server:

```
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO [' +@tableName+'] (timeStamp) VALUES (''' +
             CONVERT(nvarchar, @timeStamp, 126) + ''')'
EXEC (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dates in many coding languages and SQL are not always interchangeable.

Your problem is most likely your system time settings for where the C# code is running sending the date as `m/d/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM` (`2/25/2011 11:12:13 AM`) and SQL Server is expecting `d/m/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM` (`25/2/2011 11:12:13 AM`)

So the 25th month is out of range for SQL Server.

You are better off specifying the date in ISO format when you send it from your program to another system.

```
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
```

You can see a list of `DateTime` formats here http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format
Always leave as little as possible to system defaults.

Comment: The best advice is usually to avoid treating dates or other more structured objects as strings, *at all*, if possible. You're correct that different systems have different ways of representing dates, but for a case such as this (.NET -> SQL Server), ADO.Net knows how to translate between .NET `DateTime` and SQL Server `datetime` objects. There's no need to convert to a string and open yourself up to the possibility of the *strings* being ambiguous or capable of producing errors.